# Cloud9 IDE Stop button stops showing, Run immediately changes to Start

Tags: cloud9

I've had great success with Cloud9 IDE in prototyping Node.js applications. Up until recently it was working perfectly. Then, for no apparent reason, the "Run" button that turns into "Stop" whenever the application is started stopped showing. Instead, the button immediately reverts to "Start".

This means that my applications are never stopped unless I manually type "pkill node" and "pkill nodejs", and so I get duplicate servers and the error "warn: error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE".

Is this a Cloud9 bug, or somehow my fault?

Comment: Same bug appened to me. It seems to be cloud9 related. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: Nope, I'm fairly certain it's a Cloud9 issue. I've since stopped developing with them.

Comment: Ok, I still use it. For now the problem seems to be happening quite randomly and after a while always disapear (I think rebooting c9 server solves the issue). I think I'll keep using it coz I didn't find any IDE working well with node.js (for now).